# React Routing +URL Rewrite +IIS+ component match

Tags: reactjs, routes

Using URL Rewrite works fine and navigates to index.html. But how to navigate to the exact component. Redirecting to index.html will show my home page. what if i have multiple components and i want to match the exact component as well?

Is it possible to host a react app in IIS and to do URL rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

Is your app in the root directory your the IIS Site? I have http://myserver:5999/abc/123 working (where abc and 123 are my route params).